# How to add custom items with default items in Context Menu of handsontable

Tags: javascript, jquery, handsontable

I tried to use handsontable and want to add custom items to context menu.

There are many tutorials to implement custom menus, but it ignores the default items.

So I added keys of all items, but some of them don't work.

My setting is like follows.

```
var basicSettings = {
    minRows: 1,
    minCols: 1,
    rowHeaders: false,
    colHeaders: false,
    hiddenColumns: true,
    contextMenu: {
        items: {
            row_above: {},
            row_below: {},
            "hsep1": "---------",
            col_left: {},
            col_right: {},
            "hsep2": "---------",
            remove_row: {},
            remove_col: {},
            "hsep3": "---------",
            undo: {},
            redo: {},
            "hsep4": "---------",
            make_read_only: {},
            "hsep5": "---------",
            alignment: {},
            "hsep6": "---------",
            copy: {},
            cut: {},
            "paste": {
                name: 'Paste',
                callback: function (key, option) {
                    this.copyPaste.triggerPaste();
                }
            },
            "hsep7": "---------",
            mergeCells: {
                name: "Merge"
            },
            "hsep8": "---------",
            // Custom menu item to set color of cells
            set_color: {
                key: "color",
                name: "Color",
                "submenu": {
                    "items": [
                        {
                            key: "color:1",
                            "name": "Black",
                            callback: function(key, options) {
                                for (var i = options[0].start.row; i <= options[0].end.row; i ++){
                                    for (var j = options[0].start.col; j <= options[0].end.col; j ++){
                                        this.getCell(i, j).className = "color-black";
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }, {
                            key: "color:2",
                            "name": "White",
                            callback: function(key, options) {
                                for (var i = options[0].start.row; i <= options[0].end.row; i ++){
                                    for (var j = options[0].start.col; j <= options[0].end.col; j ++){
                                        $(this.getCell(i, j)).removeClass("color-*").addClass("color-white");
                                    }
                                }
                                this.render();
                            }
                        }, {
                            key: "color:3",
                            "name": "Red",
                            callback: function(key, options) {
                                for (var i = options[0].start.row; i <= options[0].end.row; i ++){
                                    for (var j = options[0].start.col; j <= options[0].end.col; j ++){
                                        this.getCell(i, j).style.backgroundColor = "red";
                                    }
                                }
                                this.render();
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    },
    manualRowResize: true,
    manualColumnResize: true,
    contextMenuCopyPaste: {
        swfPath: '/bower_components/zeroclipboard/dist/ZeroClipboard.swf'
    },
    copyPaste: true,
    mergeCells: true,
    search: true,
    stretchH: 'all',
    autoColumnSize: {useHeaders: true},
    autoRowSize: {syncLimit: 300},
    width: 1000,
    height: window.innerHeight - 100,
    licenseKey: "xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx"
};
```

Menu looks like this.

[image: Current Menu]

## Question 1:

Is there any way to add custom item with all the default menu items? If so, I don't need answers to Question 3 and Question 4.

## Question 2:

The most important part that let me ask this question is custom menu, that is "set_color".
After clicking "Black" or "Red", it turns into that color, but after I change value of a cell, it turns back.
How can I prevent the cells from turning their background color back?

## Questions 3:

I want additional custom item besides all feature enabled. But I can't find proper key for "Merge" item. The current "Merge" function works so strangely.
How to make the function works correctly?

## Question 4:

I tried https://github.com/handsontable/handsontable/issues/2853 to implement paste functionality, but I see this error.

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'triggerPaste' of undefined`

Please help me with those handsontable usage. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## For Question 1:

> Is there any way to add custom item with all the default menu items?
>   If so, I don't need answers to Question 3 and Question 4.

Initialize `Handsontable` with `contextMenu` set to a `true`. Example:

```
  let
    example3 = document.getElementById('example3'),
    settings3,
    hot3;

  settings3 = {
    data: [...],
    rowHeaders: true,
    colHeaders: true,
    contextMenu: true // set to `true`..
  };
  hot3 = new Handsontable(example3, settings3);
```

Then update the `contextMenu` setting like this:

```
  let cm = hot3.getPlugin('ContextMenu');
  hot3.updateSettings({
    contextMenu: {
        // Clone the pre-defined items and add your custom items.
      items: Object.assign({}, cm.itemsFactory.predefinedItems, {
        'hsep1': '---------',
        'set_color': {
            key: 'color',
            name: 'Color',
          submenu: {
            items: [{
              key: 'color:red',
              name: 'Red',
              callback: setCellColor
            }, {
              key: 'color:blue',
              name: 'Blue',
              callback: setCellColor
            }]
          }
        }
      })
    }
  });
```

## For Question 2:

> The most important part that let me ask this question is custom menu,
>   that is "set_color". After clicking "Black" or "Red", it turns into
>   that color, but after I change value of a cell, it turns back. How can
>   I prevent the cells from turning their background color back?

I'm not sure how to *prevent* that; however, here's one way to *restore* the color (or any other custom/meta data..) of the appropriate cells.

```
  // This is my callback for the 'set_color' context menu items.
  // Sample `key`: 'color:red'
  function setCellColor(key, opt) {
    let color = key.substring(6);
    for (let i = opt[0].start.row; i <= opt[0].end.row; i++) {
      for (let j = opt[0].start.col; j <= opt[0].end.col; j++) {
        this.getCell(i, j).style.color = color;
        this.setCellMeta(i, j, 'color', color); // Save the color
      }
    }
  }

  // Listen to the `beforeRenderer` event, and restore the cell's color
  // before the "renderer" starting rendering the cell
  Handsontable.hooks.add('beforeRenderer', function(td, r, c, p, pv, cp){
    if (cp.color) {
        td.style.color = cp.color;
    }
  }, hot3);
```

## Demo

Try the full example here: http://jsfiddle.net/y9j3m29c/1/, which is based on https://docs.handsontable.com/3.0.0/demo-context-menu.html#page-custom

## For the Paste functionality:

Load `SheetClip()`:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/sheetclip"></script>
```

Add the necessary variables:

```
let clipboardCache = '';
const sheetclip = new SheetClip();
```

Add the necessary callbacks:

```
  settings3 = {
    ...
    afterCopy: function(changes){
        clipboardCache = sheetclip.stringify(changes);
    },
    afterCut: function(changes){
        clipboardCache = sheetclip.stringify(changes);
    },
    afterPaste: function(changes){
        clipboardCache = sheetclip.stringify(changes);
    }
  };
```

Add the context menu item:

```
  let cm = hot3.getPlugin('ContextMenu');
  hot3.updateSettings({
    contextMenu: {
        // Clone the pre-defined items and add your custom items.
      items: Object.assign({}, cm.itemsFactory.predefinedItems, {
        ...
        'paste': {
            name: 'Paste',
          disabled: function(){
            return clipboardCache.length === 0;
          },
          callback: function(){
            var plugin = this.getPlugin('copyPaste');

            this.listen();
            plugin.paste(clipboardCache);
          }
        }
      })
    }
  });
```

More details on https://docs.handsontable.com/3.0.0/demo-copy-paste.html#paste-in-context-menu and demo on http://jsfiddle.net/y9j3m29c/2/ — or http://jsfiddle.net/y9j3m29c/4/ which comes with a "Clear clipboard" functionality.

Comment: Great! +1. Your answers are awesome, especially the one for Question 1. But I expect further answers to implement "paste" functionality. So I will wait to mark your answer as accepted. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the +1! Please check the updated answer. =)

Comment: Totally awesome. I want to give +10, if I can. Thanks for your wonderful answer !!!

Comment: Is it possible to change background Color same like color?

Comment: @SudhakarAyyar, yes it's possible. Check out and try [this](http://jsfiddle.net/cxzobqkj/).